# How to reference netcoreapp from test project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I need to spin up a [TestHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) in my integration test project.  I want to use the startup class in my API project.  I want to know if it is possible to add a reference to my API project from my Test project and if so, how do I do it.
Thanks.

integration test project

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "ProjectManager.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Gateway": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.REST": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.WCF": "1.0.0-*",
    "NUnit": "3.5.0",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3",
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "Autofac": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "netcoreapp1.1",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.3.0",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0"
      }
    },
    "net462": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {}
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit"
}
```

api project

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ProjectManager.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Gateway": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.REST": "1.0.0-*",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Autofac": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0"

  },

  "tools": {
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {}
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Edit per Nate's answer.  Revised project.json in test project and error msg:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "ProjectManager.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Gateway": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.REST": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.Services.WCF": "1.0.0-*",
    "ProjectManager.API": {"target": "project", "version": "1.0.0-*"},
    "NUnit": "3.5.0",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3",
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "Autofac": "4.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "netcoreapp1.1",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.3.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.3.0",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0"
      }
    },
    "net462": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {}
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit"
}
```

Error Message:

```
    PATH=C:\Program files\nodejs;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\.vs\restore.dg"
    log  : Restoring packages for C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\project.json...
    error: Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
    error: Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
    error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
    error: Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
    error: Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
    error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
    log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\project.lock.json
    log  : C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\ProjectManager.Tests.xproj
    log  : Restore failed in 5641ms.
    Errors in C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\ProjectManager.Tests.xproj
        Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
        Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
        One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
        Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
        Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
        One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
    PATH=C:\Program files\nodejs;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\.vs\restore.dg"
    log  : Restoring packages for C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\project.json...
    error: Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
    error: Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
    error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
    error: Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
    error: Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
    error: One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
    error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
    log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\project.lock.json
    log  : C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\ProjectManager.Tests.xproj
    log  : Restore failed in 5266ms.
    Errors in C:\Git\ProjectManager\ProjectManager\src\ProjectManager.Tests\ProjectManager.Tests.xproj
        Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
        Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
        One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
        Project ProjectManager.API is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Project ProjectManager.API supports: netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
        Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0 supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
        One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
        One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win10-x64).
```

Comment: add to dependencies

Comment: Do you need to specify `runtimes: win10-x64`? That's typically not necessary. Also, why does the integration test project target `net462` as well as `netcoreapp1.1`?

Comment: When I remove runtimes and use type:platform in Microsoft.NETCore.App IIS fails.  Also, I have a WPF project that depends on same models and services as API project.

Comment: BTW I'm open to trying anything.  I've been at this for a couple days now.  Fixing A breaks B and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your projects are in the same directory tree (for example, in `src/` and `test/` folders under the root project directory), add this to the `dependencies` section of the integration test project:

```
"MyApiProject": {
  "target": "project"
}
```

The `target: project` flag tells NuGet to skip looking for a package and reference the local project.

Comment: Thank you Nate.  I implemented your answer.  Revised project.json and error msg are shown in my question.  Also, projects are in same directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I use `xUnit` in my tests, but I also add a reference to my API in my Test project.
I'm gonna post my project configuration. Take a look and check if it helps you.
In case you want to take a look in the complete code, check this [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular/tree/master/Part2).

project.json from Test Project:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "WebApp": "1.0.0-*",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `WebApp` is my API.

TestServerFixture class to inject the server into the test case:

```
public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable {
  private TestServer testServer;
  protected TestServer TestServer {
    get {
      if (testServer == null) {
        testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
      }
      return testServer;
    }
  }

  public HttpClient Client {
    get {
      return TestServer.CreateClient();
    }
  }
  public void Dispose() {
    if (testServer != null) {
      testServer.Dispose();
      testServer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

An example of integration test:

```
public class PersonControllerTest : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture> {
  public PersonControllerTest(TestServerFixture fixture) {
    Fixture = fixture;
  }

  protected TestServerFixture Fixture { get; private set; }

  [Fact]
  public async void ItShouldReturnSomething() {
    using (var client = Fixture.Client) {
      var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/person");
      string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      IList<PersonModel> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<PersonModel>>(json);
      Assert.True(list.Count == 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work unfortunately.  Nice tutorial BTW.

Comment: adding the reference didn't work? Did you try it with xUnit?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I could not implement the answer provided by Nate was that I was running into the issue described here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/538

The answer was to reinstall the sdk found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core